# Python order dataframe alphabetically

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to reorder dataframe by student name. 
Does anybody have some suggestions?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'student': [
            'monica', 'nathalia', 'anastasia', 'marina', 'ema'
        ],

    'grade' : ['excellent', 'excellent', 'good', 'very good', 'good'
    ]
    })

    print (df)

                student   grade

        0       monica    excellent        
        1       nathalia  excellent         
        2       anastasia good        
        3       marina    very good          
        4       ema       good
```

Comment: suppose if you want the sort the dataframe alphabateically as well as length wise(greater to lesser), how would you do it ?

Comment: I'm glad you asked this! Big help!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Pre pandas 0.17:

```
# Sort by ascending student name
df.sort('student')
# reverse ascending
df.sort('student', ascending=False)
```

Pandas 0.17+ (as mentioned in the other answers):

```
# ascending
df.sort_values('student')
# reverse ascending
df.sort_values('student', ascending=False)
```

Comment: Just a little remainder, don't forget to assign the sorted df back. I was scratching my head and wondering why the code didn't work haha.

Answer (score 13):

**pandas 0.19.2**

```
df.sort_values(by=['contig', 'pos'], ascending=True)

# where contig and pos are the column names. So, you may change for yours.
```

**Note:** Use of `inplace` is very essential if you want to update the same dataframe. Most of the people run into confusion about when to use/not-use inplace.

**If you want to make a new-dataframe.**

```
df_sorted = df.sort_values(by=['contig', 'pos'], inplace=False, ascending=True)
```

Comment: +1 for the `inplace`. I have had so many headaches over following tutorials that say it restructures your data but doesn't add `inplace` so if you print it off it look the same.

Answer (score 8):

You can sort a dataframe using the `sort_values` method.

```
df.sort_values('student')
```

Answer (score 3):

try

```
df.sort_values(by='student')
```

or, if you want Z first:

```
df.sort_values(by='student', ascending=False)
```

Answer (score 3):

`pd.DataFrame.sort_values` is the obvious `pandas` choice

However, you can use `numpy` and reconstruct.  This will give you a modest performance boost.

```
a = df.student.values.astype(str).argsort()
pd.DataFrame(df.values[a], df.index[a], df.columns)

       grade    student
2       good  anastasia
4       good        ema
3  very good     marina
0  excellent     monica
1  excellent   nathalia
```

***testing over small data***
[image]

***testing over larger data***
[image]

Comment: I didn't expect Pandas to be almost 3 times slower for this bigger DF...

Answer (score 1):

You can do something similar if you're reading from a csv file.

```py
df.sort_values(by=['student'])
```